# Symfony firewall configuration: no anonymous in my admin back-office

Tags: php, symfony

I'm building my first website with symfony so my question shouldn't be hard to solve. I have a back-office part in my website having that kind of url

```
http://www.mysupersite.com/admin
```

In this admoin section I would like to deny access for all anonymous users by using the symfony firewall. But with my security.yml configuration I have this error

```
No authentication listener registered for firewall "admin".
```

Please could you take a look at my security.yml and tell me where I'm wrong ?

```
security:

    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory: ~
        main:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false             

        login:
            pattern:   ^/(login$|register|resetting)
            anonymous: true

        admin:
            pattern: ^/admin
            anonymous: false
            provider: main

        main:
            # form_login: ~
            pattern:        ^/
            anonymous:      true
            provider:       main
            form_login:
                login_path: /login
                check_path: /login_check
            logout:
                path:       /logout
                target:     /
            remember_me:
                secret:        %secret% #%secret% est un paramètre de parameters.yml
```

Answer (score 1):

I'bve found the answer by myself. Here is the security.yml I'm using.

```
    security:

    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory: ~
        main:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false             

        main:
            # form_login: ~
            pattern:        ^/
            anonymous:      true
            provider:       main
            form_login:
                login_path: /login
                check_path: /login_check
            logout:
                path:       /logout
                target:     /
            remember_me:
                secret:        %secret% #%secret% est un paramètre de parameters.yml
   access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN   }
```

Comment: I had the same problem, I removed my admin config also and it works..untill now :p